# I want to predict future interest rates. Should I use dates as a variable for my prediction?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python

To predict interest rates I am using CPI, fed funding rate, yearly average housing prices, and interest rate. I have all my data set up to what year it is, for example, 1971-01-01 has a CPI x, IR x, FED rate x, and price x. I guess what I am trying to see is if I can use the dates not just as an index but to predict future IR. I am using Linear Regression. [image]

Comment: *"Should I use dates as a variable for my prediction?"* What do you mean by this? Obviously your data should contain dates because that allows you to order the data as a time sequence. Or do you mean something more elaborate like using specific dates of the year as a predictor for seasonal effects? Or to add time trends that you extrapolate to the future?